# Oracle - CPU utilization by an Oracle job?

Tags: oracle

> > What is the way to know the CPU utilization of an Oracle job throughout its execution?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the CPU Utilised by an oracle process in the past you may want to obtain an AWR report which gives you exhaustive details.

If you want to know the CPU utilisation in real time, if you have access to OEM, it can show you in real time the CPU utilisation of your specific oracle process.

If you don't have access to OEM, your DBA should be able to check and give you the details about your oracle process.

Last but not the least, there are lots of dynamic performance views like v$session, v$sql etc. One or more of these dynamic performance views will give you the details you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The total amount of CPU utilization is stored in DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS_RUN_DETAILS.CPU_USED.  It can be found with a query like this:

```
select cpu_used, dba_scheduler_job_run_details.*
from dba_scheduler_job_run_details
where job_name = 'MY_JOB' --name of job
    and trunc(log_date) = date '2016-04-22';  --date of job
```

If you want more details like point-in-time CPU usage, that would be a more difficult question and would require some more clarification.